# Estimating tilt angles of a body around three arbitrary axis

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I know a rotation matrix (or quaternion) of a body in starting position and in end position. The body was tilted in between around three vectors which are known. Is there a way to estimate the angles the body was tilted around these vectors just by knowing the end orientation of the body?

Answer (score 0):

If  body rotation is limited in given time period (for example, it does not accomplish two turnovers etc) and direction changes smoothly, then you can consider using of  SLERP - [spherical linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp).

If you have initial tilt vector p0 (consisting of  [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine)) and ending p1, you can use geometric SLERP to get direction cosines as components of interpolated direction vector

Comment: I think this will not give me the x,y,z angles of each axis, but just the intermediate rotation quaternion

Comment: Thanks, is this approach working the same for three consecutive axis?